# Path of Logback.xml file in AEM 6.3

Tags: logging, aem

We are doing slf4j with log back implementation in AEM project. We understood that in logback.xml we have to write the appenders (these appenders would have custom message format). The only thing which is not clear to us is the path where this logback.xml should be stored. Can someone provide any pointers regarding where logback.xml should be stored in AEM project hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

In AEM, the logger message format is stored as an OSGI configuration, 
You can access the logging configuration in path,
http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr

The logger configuration can be found by name **"Apache Sling Logging Configuration"**.
Property "*message pattern*" found within this configuration controls the pattern in which the log information are captured.